# Can you beautify jekyll html output at build time

Tags: html, jekyll

Is there a way to automatically beautify the html output from Jekyll after it builds the site directory?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way should be using [Jekyll::Tidy](https://github.com/apsislabs/jekyll-tidy) plugin.

Just add following to your `_config.yml`:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-tidy
```

---

However for me it does not does not produce pretty HTML with correct indentation.

If you are OK depending on Node.js, using [`pretty` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty) produces pretty results and is the only way which worked 100% correct for me. Just wrap it to simple script and run after building your site.

You can also checkout my blog post [Pretty HTML with Jekyll](https://blog.lukaskukacka.com/jekyll/2018/10/21/pretty-html-with-jekyll.html) where I describe my solution based on [`pretty` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty) more in detail.

Comment: +1. I just used this now, with your custom implementation from the blog post, and it works perfectly well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to beautify or minimize/tidy your HTML? If you just want to get smaller HTML, I'd suggest to give [octopress minify-html](https://github.com/octopress/minify-html) a try,  really does its job. 
If you want to have nice HTML tidy HTML is fine (linked above)